# Delete files from server and database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very basic file uploading page. 
If you are logged in, you see a page (myFiles.php) where I have a table of files uploaded by the user that's logged in + a delete button for each row. I get the user files from my database, where I have a table Uploads(filename, extension, filemtime, username) with this code:

```
 if ($_SESSION['active'] == true) {
                echo "<table class='table'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                    <th></th>
                    </tr>";
                $query = "SELECT filename, filemtime, username FROM Uploads WHERE username='".$active."' ORDER BY filemtime"; //
                $result = mysql_query($query);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $timestamp = strtotime($row["filemtime"]);
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["filename"]. "</td><td>" . date("d.m.Y",$timestamp). "</td>";
                    echo "<td><form role='form' action='delete_check.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
                    echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button></form></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "</table>";
}
```

I need to know how can I connect the delete button to that certain row and how to pass arguments (filename and extension) to the page where I delete the file from database and my server (page delete_check.php).

delete_check.php looks currently like this (this isn't working because I can't pass the arguments from delete.php):

```
    session_start();
    $active = $_SESSION['active'];

    $con = mysql_connect("database","user","pw");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database", $con);


    $file = "upload/".$filename.".".$extension;
    unlink($filename);

    $query = "DELETE FROM Uploads WHERE filename='".$filename."'";
    $delete = MYSQL_QUERY($query);
    if ($delete === true ) {
        echo "Deleted from database ".$filename." extension: " . $extension;
    } else {
        echo "Not deleted ".$filename." extension: " . $extension;
    }
    //header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: put the filename as a input hidden field in html, value = filename :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you to add an unique autoincrement id to every row in your database. So that the struct looks like that:

```
id| filename| filemtime| username ...
1 |  *      |   *      |    *
2 |  *      |   *      |    *
...
```

Now u can Select the datas with the following SQL Statement

```
 $query = "SELECT id, filename, filemtime, username FROM Uploads WHERE username='".$active."' ORDER BY filemtime"; //
```

Now add the id to the delete form like that:

```
echo "<td><form role='form' action='delete_check.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$row["id"]."\">;
echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button></form></td>";
```

In your delete_check.php you can now select the id by `$id = $_POST['id']`. SQL Statement would look like this

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Uploads WHERE id=".$id;
```

But take care! You also should check if the given id is attached to the current user if you dont want that users can delete attachments which are not assigned to them. You may extend the delete sql statement in something like that:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Uploads WHERE id=".$id." AND WHERE username LIKE '".$active."'";
```

Comment: Finally got it to work, used the hidden input to also pass file name & extension to remove file from server. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

Using JavaScript, have each button redirect to `delete_check.php` while passing the filename (assuming it is unique identifier; I prefer to have a column called id to act as unique identifier in my tables).

```
  echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"window.location='delete_check.php?filename=$filename'\">Delete</button></form></td>";
```

At the top of `delete_check.php`,

```
  $filename = isset($_GET['filename']) ? $_GET['filename'] : null;
```

And just like how you did in the first part, you query the row with an additional condition. You need to do this or else any file can be deleted by any user.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Uploads WHERE username='$active' AND filename='$filename'";

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

And proceed with deleting the file and row from table.

```
  unlink("upload/{$row['filename']}.{$row['extension']}");

  $query = "DELETE FROM Uploads WHERE username='$active' AND filename='{$row['filename']}'";
```